# Why python time has 61 seconds

Tags: python

Did anybody notice that the interval of second in Python datetime is [00,61]
see the table on this page.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Why?

Comment: Day of year also goes from [1, 366] in order to accomodate leap days.

Comment: -1 because +6 for a question answered in the link it contains is ridiculous.

Comment: "_-1 because +6 for a question answered in the link it contains is ridiculous_"
The question is not actually answered by the link. Leap seconds are noted, but that only explains _half_ of the question.

Answer (score 21):

The answer is on the same page in footnote (2):

> The range really is 0 to 61; value 60 is valid in timestamps representing leap seconds and value 61 is supported for historical reasons.

The "historical reasons" are described in https://bugs.python.org/issue2568.

Comment: hmm,I too exiting to ignore the explanation.

Comment: I just realized that Python doesn't have a database of leap seconds (akin to tzinfo for timezones) and so doesn't have a way to validate if a certain leap second is legit... this means that conversion to Unix time is lossy: `t1=time.strptime("30 Jun 1997 23:59:60", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"); t2=time.strptime("01 Jul 1997 00:00:00", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")`, then `t1 == t2` yields `False` as expected, but `calendar.timegm(t1) == calendar.timegm(t2)` yields `True`

Comment: @berdario: your example is (accidently?) correct. There is [a leap second on 30 Jun 1997](http://tf.nist.gov/pubs/bulletin/leapsecond.htm). And there is always 86400 seconds in a POSIX day therefore `calendar.timegm()` returns correct results ([the same POSIX timestamp occurs twice in this case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number)).

Comment: The tz database (available via `pytz` Python package) has a list of leap seconds. [You could use it, to check whether given time is a leap second.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19332902/4279)

Comment: Note for further readers: there has never been a double leap second, and never will be.  Apparently Posix standardized this incorrectly, and we're left with this abomination.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a double leap second. There cannot be 62 seconds in a minute. 59, yes. 60, yes. 61, yes. 62, no.

http://www.monkey.org/openbsd/archive2/tech/199905/msg00031.html

Comment: Well, can you give a single case of "inverse leap second", e.g. when was the minute, having 59 seconds instead of 60?

Comment: There have been no examples of a 59 second minute, however in theory there could be. There cannot be a "double leap second" though.

Comment: Double leap seconds are permitted, there just haven't been any to date. So a minute could have 62 seconds -- it's just that such has yet to occur.

Comment: Chris, the mythical "double leap seconds" cannot happen due to the definitions of the ITU-R. The specifications are hard to get, and someone misread them. Under the current systems there will never be a double leap second, and the odds of there ever being a 59 second minute is very small.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, but there is [this](https://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/onlinebib.html), which seems to have good coverage of the relevant minutiae.

Comment: FYI I believe this is a mirror of the original (dead) link: https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=92682843416159&w=2

Answer (score 2):

Probably to account for [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Answer (score 0):

When you have to add leap second it will be helpful to calculate that. You can search on net for leap second. Due to that second range in python is `0-61`.

Comment: Actually it's up to 61 for double leap seconds.

Comment: @plaes Where's the proof that those exist? Simply issuing two leap second months in a row would suffice without stretching a minute up even further.

Comment: So far there has been none. But leap seconds cannot be predicted.

Answer (score -7):

Leap seconds.

It has been the case that there have been 62 seconds in a minute in the past.

It adjusts for the world spinning slower.

Part of this is down to tides. The energy for the tides comes from the rotation of the earth and moon. The result is that the world slows down.

If global warming takes place the oceans get hotter and expand. That is like a skater throwing their arms out, and the spin slows down. That hasn't taken place. The measurement of ocean levels doesn't agree with the rotation measurements. It's likely to be down to problems with the earth's surface moving, which is far larger than the sea level rise.

Comment: Global warning is not responsible for leap seconds. This is just confusion added to an already complex topic.

Comment: There has never been 62 seconds per minute in the past, not even in theory!