# How to get current date and time from GPS unsegment time in python

Tags: python, datetime, gps

I have gps unsegmented time like this:

```
Tgps = 1092121243.0
```

And I'd like to understand what date and time is that. The begining of GPS time is 6 January 1980. Python function

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp
```

could give seconds from 1 January 1970 year.

I found following:

```
from datetime import datetime
GPSfromUTC = (datetime(1980,1,6) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
curDate = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(Tgps + GPSfromUTC) 

Out[83]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 7, 0, 43)
```

I'm not sure about leapseconds are they included in function datetime or I should calculate them and substract from the result?
May be also exists better solution of this problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

GPS time started in sync with UTC: `1980-01-06 (UTC) == 1980-01-06 (GPS)`. Both tick in SI seconds. The difference between GPS time and UTC time increases with each (intercalary) leap second.

To find the correct UTC time, you need to know the number of leap seconds occurred before the given GPS time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# utc = 1980-01-06UTC + (gps - (leap_count(2014) - leap_count(1980)))
utc = datetime(1980, 1, 6) + timedelta(seconds=1092121243.0 - (35 - 19))
print(utc)
```

#### Output

```
2014-08-15 07:00:27 # (UTC)
```

where `leap_count(date)` is the number of leap seconds introduced before the given date. From [TAI-UTC table](http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/index.php?index=TAI-UTC_tab&lang=en) (note: the site is the authoritative source on leap seconds. It publishes [Bulletin C announcing new leap seconds](http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/index.php?index=bulletins)):

```
1980..: 19s 
2012..: 35s
```

and therefore:

```
(leap_count(2014) - leap_count(1980)) == (35 - 19)
```

---

If you are on Unix then you could use `"right"` time zone to get UTC time from TAI time
(and it is easy to get TAI time from GPS time: [TAI = GPS + 19 seconds (constant offset)](http://www.leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time

os.environ['TZ'] = 'right/UTC' # TAI scale with 1970-01-01 00:00:10 (TAI) epoch
time.tzset() # Unix

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

gps_timestamp = 1092121243.0 # input
gps_epoch_as_gps = datetime(1980, 1, 6) 
# by definition
gps_time_as_gps = gps_epoch_as_gps + timedelta(seconds=gps_timestamp) 
gps_time_as_tai = gps_time_as_gps + timedelta(seconds=19) # constant offset
tai_epoch_as_tai = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 10)
# by definition
tai_timestamp = (gps_time_as_tai - tai_epoch_as_tai).total_seconds() 
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(tai_timestamp)) # "right" timezone is in effect!
```

#### Output

```
2014-08-15 07:00:27 # (UTC)
```

---

You could avoid changing the timezone if you extract the leap seconds list from the corresponding [`tzfile(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html). It is a combination of the first two methods where the leap count computation from the first method is automated and the autoupdating `tzdata` (system package for [the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)) from the second method is used:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> import leapseconds
>>> leapseconds.gps_to_utc(datetime(1980,1,6) + timedelta(seconds=1092121243.0))
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 7, 0, 27)
```

where [`leapseconds.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/92df922103ac9deb1a05) can extract leap seconds from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/UTC` file (part of `tzdata` package).

All three methods produce the same result.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [astropy.time](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/) package to do this:

#### GPS time to TAI

```
from astropy.time import Time
mytime = 1092121243.0
t = Time(mytime, format='gps')
t = Time(t, format='iso') # same as scale='tai'
print(t)
```

which returns `2014-08-15 07:01:02.000`

#### GPS time to UTC

```
from astropy.time import Time
sec = 1092121243.0
t_in = Time(sec, format='gps')
t_out = Time(t_in, format='iso', scale='utc')
print(t_out)
```

which outputs `2014-08-15 07:00:27.000`

Answer (score 7):

I use the following function that counts leap seconds:

```
import bisect
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

_LEAP_DATES = ((1981, 6, 30), (1982, 6, 30), (1983, 6, 30),
               (1985, 6, 30), (1987, 12, 31), (1989, 12, 31),
               (1990, 12, 31), (1992, 6, 30), (1993, 6, 30),
               (1994, 6, 30), (1995, 12, 31), (1997, 6, 30),
               (1998, 12, 31), (2005, 12, 31), (2008, 12, 31),
               (2012, 6, 30), (2015, 6, 30), (2016, 12, 31))

LEAP_DATES = tuple(datetime(i[0], i[1], i[2], 23, 59, 59) for i in _LEAP_DATES)

def leap(date):
    """
    Return the number of leap seconds since 1980-01-01

    :param date: datetime instance
    :return: leap seconds for the date (int)
    """
    # bisect.bisect returns the index `date` would have to be
    # inserted to keep `LEAP_DATES` sorted, so is the number of
    # values in `LEAP_DATES` that are less than `date`, or the
    # number of leap seconds.
    return bisect.bisect(LEAP_DATES, date)
```

Of course, you need to update `_LEAP_DATES` occasionally, but these updates are quite rare.

In general, GPS time consists of two numbers: *GPS week* and the number of *seconds* since the beginning of the current GPS week. Therefore, you can use the following:

```
def gps2utc(week, secs):
    """
    :param week: GPS week number, i.e. 1866
    :param secs: number of seconds since the beginning of `week`
    :return: datetime instance with UTC time
    """
    secs_in_week = 604800
    gps_epoch = datetime(1980, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0)
    date_before_leaps = gps_epoch + timedelta(seconds=week * secs_in_week + secs)
    return date_before_leaps - timedelta(seconds=leap(date_before_leaps))
```

In your case `week = 0`, so:

```
In [1]: gps2utc(0, 1092121243.0)
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 7, 0, 27)
```

Comment: to be sure your code is up-to-date, you have to consult [Bulletin C](ftp://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/bulletinc.dat) twice a year (and theoretically, 4 times a year). You could [use `"right/UTC"`, tzfile-based solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33426779/4279) that rely on automatically updated `tzdata` system package.

Answer (score 1):

A linear combination between [Ru887321](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838347/4562968) and [Yury Kirienko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772372/4562968) answers.

```
from astropy.time import Time

def gps2utc(gpsweek, gpsseconds):
    """ GPS time to UTC.

    Parameters
    ----------
    gpsweek : int
        GPS week number, i.e. 1866.
    gpsseconds : int
        Number of seconds since the beginning of week.

    Returns
    -------
    datetime
        datetime instance with UTC time.
    """
    secs_in_week = 604800
    secs = gpsweek * secs_in_week + gpsseconds

    t_gps = Time(secs, format="gps")
    t_utc = Time(t_gps, format="iso", scale="utc")

    return t_utc.datetime
```

In your case `week = 0`, so:

```
In [1]: gps2utc(0, 1092121243.0)
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 7, 0, 27)
```