# Conversion from UNIX time to timestamp starting in January 1, 2000

Tags: python, datetime, unix, timestamp, epoch

I am trying to interact with an API that uses a timestamp that starts at a different time than UNIX epoch. It appears to start counting on 2000-01-01, but I'm not sure exactly how to do the conversion or what the name of this datetime format is.

When I send a message at 1456979510 I get a response back saying it was received at 510294713.
The difference between the two is 946684796 (sometimes 94668479**7**) seconds, which is approximately 30 years.

Can anyone let me know the proper way to convert between the two? Or whether I can generate them outright in Python?

Thanks

**Edit**

An additional detail I should have mentioned is that this is an API to a Zigbee device. I found the following datatype entry in their documentation:

> 1.3.2.7 Absolute time
>   This is an unsigned 32-bit integer representation for absolute time. Absolute time is measured in seconds
>   from midnight, 1st January 2000.

I'm still not sure the easiest way to convert between the two

Comment: Could you give us a sample input? In what format will the input date be in?

Comment: This part if the input is only documented as a UInt32, and requests are sent as SOAP messages. I'm doing my end using Python and the suds library, they are running C#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The time **1 January 1970 00:00:00** is considered the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). So, if you want to convert from UNIX time to a timestamp having an epoch of January 1, 2000 (Let's say, 2000 epoch) the simplest way would be to simply subtract the UNIX time of January 1, 2000 from the UNIX time.

```
<2000 time> = <UNIX time> - <January 1, 2000 UNIX time>

<UNIX time> = <2000 time> + <January 1, 2000 UNIX time>
```

Where January 1, 2000 UNIX time is **946684800**.

**EDIT:** The docs does say

> Absolute time is measured in seconds from midnight, 1st January 2000.

So, `946684800` is the *exact time difference* which should be used to calculate. The few seconds difference that you calculated could be attributed to network delay or some other delays.

Comment: This is naively correct, but there's going to be difference (see my post about how the difference is actually 946684797)  
I'm not sure if this is due to leap seconds perhaps? I was hoping there would be a more accurate way to convert, particularly using Python.

Comment: @TomSitter - Well, the docs does say "_Absolute time is measured in seconds from midnight, 1st January 2000_". So, `946684800` is the exact time difference to calculate. The few seconds could be attributed to the network delay or other delays.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll do that.

Comment: @TomSitter: it may be incorrect. The device may count *elapsed* seconds while Unix time is usually is a POSIX time and therefore *leap* seconds are NOT counted. Here's a [code example on how to convert GPS time (1980 epoch) to UTC (POSIX)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33415475/4279). In your case the formula is: `utc_time =  datetime(2000, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=510294713 - (36 - 32))` that is earlier by one second then the sent time (`1456979510`): sent  (host) time: `4:31:50`, received (device) time: `4:31:49` if we assume POSIX time on host, and TAI with 2000-01-01UTC epoch on the device.

Comment: the [ZIGBEE spec](http://contech.suv.ac.kr/contech/courses/11h2wsn/075366r01ZB_AFG-ZigBee_Cluster_Library_Public_download_version.pdf) uses `UTCTime` for the type: *"UTCTime is an unsigned 32 bit value representing the number of seconds since 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, on the 1st of January, 2000 UTC"*. But it doesn't mention leap seconds at all and therefore it is still possible that the device measures *elapsed* seconds.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Yes, it would be more correct if the spec added *"excluding leap seconds"* at the end of that sentence, but that is generally implied.  Since these sorts of devices usually get their time set via NTP, leap seconds are already accounted for, and thus the need for the developer to concern themselves with leap seconds is mitigated.  In my experience, it is quite rare to see any device following TAI (UTC without leap seconds), unless it's directly involved with timekeeping.  GPS time is an exception, but it is not strictly TAI either (being 19 seconds behind).

Comment: @MattJohnson if the device can sync its time with UTC then it is likely the timestamp doesn't count leap seconds and the naive formula should work (both host and the device use UTC scale but with different epochs). If the device does *nothing* (no syncing) then by default leap seconds *are* counted. You have to enable syncing to *avoid* counting leap seconds. In practice, the device's clock accuracy is poor and therefore such fine points as leap seconds are irrelevant (if the error of several seconds is acceptable) -- UTC and TAI are indistinguishable in this case.

Comment: I think we're saying the same things, just in inverse context.  The time on the device *does* include leap seconds that have been applied up to when it synced.  But the `UTCTime` value is the number of seconds elapsed *not* counting them.  We're on the same page. :)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: The OP added details specifying that the time starts at *midnight* and hence it is *absolute* time different from J2000 which starts at *noon*. But since the title states "timestamp starting in January 1, 2000" I am letting this answer to be for future answer seekers.

**ANSWER:**

The timestamp you have mentioned appears to be the J2000.0 mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#J2000.0)

Since the Unix and J2000 epoch times are constants, you could define a constant to store the difference.

If you have a mathematical inclination the following links provide some info regarding the conversion

1. http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/mars24/help/algorithm.html Refer to step A-2
2. http://onegeek.org/software/smeg/current/src/time.c (C file),

   the `#define` section in the C file contains the following

   `#define J2000 2451545.0        /* you-know-when */`

   `#define U1970  -10957.5       /* unix epoch relative to J2000 */`

Comment: J2000.0 is used in astronomy, and is based on Julian days.  It uses an epoch of *noon* on 2000-01-01.  The OP's data is based on *midnight*, so this is incorrect.  Good try though.

Comment: @MattJohnson i typed the answer before the edit. Should it be edited or deleted now?

Comment: Up to you.  You can leave it if you like.

Comment: 2451545.0 ... what, exactly? what are the units here?

Comment: @MichaelBonnet it should be seconds AFAIK. Here is how its calculated: https://thecynster.home.blog/2019/11/08/calculating-the-julian-date-and-j2000/

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are 946684800 seconds between 2000-01-01T00:00:00Z and 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.   So, you can just set a constant for `946684800` and add or subtract from your Unix timestamps.

The variation you are seeing in your numbers has to do with the *delay* in sending and receiving the data, and could also be due to clock synchronization, or lack thereof.  Since these are whole seconds, and your numbers are 3 to 4 seconds off, then I would guess that the clocks between your computer and your device are also 3 to 4 seconds out of sync.

Comment: another possibility is that [the device time uses TAI scale with 2000UTC epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763357/conversion-from-unix-time-to-timestamp-starting-in-january-1-2000#comment59218585_35763683)

Comment: Well, we could speculate all day :)  But Occam's razor... It's likely just UNIX Time (aka POSIX time) offset 30 years.  Anything fancier than that requires specially designed software or hardware.

Comment: speaking of Occam's razor: do you understand that not counting leap seconds is *more* work (more complex) unless the clocks are in sync with the external source (in that case it doesn't matter what time scale is used)? So let's not speculate. 2- Unix time (the value return by time.time()) is not the same as POSIX time e.g., set TZ=right/UTC and see what happens.

Comment: See my other comment, but also, Wikipedia disagrees that Unix time and Posix time are not the same.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time   I couldn't find any other reference.  Care to elaborate on that?  Cheers!

Comment: 1- "right/UTC" is not POSIX. Agree? 2- Linux is a "Unix" for the purpose of this discussion. Agree? `time.time()` returns "seconds since epoch" (Unix time). Agree? `time.time()` returns non-POSIX timestamp in "right" timezones (fact). 3- Wikipedia is useful if you know *nothing* about a non-controversial subject i.e., you can link to it, to explain something but you should not refer to it as an *authoritative* source. You know, it is like name vs variable in Python: if we are not discussing name issues specifically; there is nothing wrong in using "variable" term otherwise use exact term: name

Answer (score 1):

The differences in the two times is indeed 30 years:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1456979510)
>>> d1.ctime()
'Wed Mar  2 20:31:50 2016'
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(510294713)
>>> d2.ctime()
'Mon Mar  3 20:31:53 1986'
```

Creating a variable to hold the difference conversion either way can be done:

```
>>> conv_factor = (d1 - d2).total_seconds()
>>> conv_factor
946684797.0
>>> conv_time = d2 + datetime.timedelta(seconds=conv_factor)
>>> conv_time
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 20, 31, 50)
>>> conv_time.ctime()
'Wed Mar  2 20:31:50 2016'
```

Subtracting the `conv_factor` works to convert the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Unix epoch:  1970-1-1, 00:00:00 UTC

J2000 epoch: 2000-1-1, 12:00:00 UTC

The time gap is: 946684800 in seconds

The pitfall is that python will use local timezone for conversion from datetime to timestamp. As shown below:

```
import datetime
import time, calendar
dt = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0) # datetime.datetime, default is computer's local time zone
tt = dt.timetuple()
print(tt) # time.struct_time
print("Unix Timestamp: ",time.mktime(tt))      # struct_time in local time
print("Unix Timestamp: ",calendar.timegm(tt))  # struct_time in UTC
```

So if you want to convert timestamp back to datetime, use these codes:

```
t = 0  # Unix timestamp
t2000 = t+946728000
#value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t2000)   # from local time
dt= datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t2000)     # from UTC time
print(dt.timetuple())
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

There is a nice conversion tool online: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php