# Get absolute time since epoch midnight Jan. 1, 1984 in Linux

Tags: c, linux, struct, timestamp

I am writing a C program on Linux with CAN functionality. I need to get the absolute time since midnight Jan. 1, 1984, in the following TIME Object format. What function should I use?

***Code***

```
typedef struct
{
    UNSIGNED32     ms; // upper 4 bits are reserved
    UNSIGNED16     days;
} TIME_OF_DAY;
```

Comment: I'm surprised I could not find a C duplicate... Here's something similar in Python: [Conversion from UNIX time to timestamp starting in January 1, 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35763357/608639).

Answer (score 2):

The usual Unix/Linux time epoch is 1 January 1970, so you can use any of the usual functions, most likely [`clock_gettime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME`.  Then simply subtract the amount of time between 1970 and 1984 (a constant you can embed in your code).

Comment: `#define days 5113`, It is calculated [with](https://planetcalc.com/273/)

Comment: Thanks @john-zwinck for the help. This works for me. However, since the conversion from seconds to milliseconds is not so straightforward using the timespec struct, I am facing difficulty in subtracting milliseconds difference between two dates.

Comment: @akashagrawal I think something along: `struct timespec s;` `TIME_OF_DAY v = { .days = s.tv_sec / (60ull * 60 * 24) - 5113, .ms = s.tv_sec % (60ull * 60 * 24) * 1000 + s.tv_nsec / (1000ull * 1000ull) }` ?