# Converting from Date-Time to GPS time

Tags: python, bash, time, gps, gps-time

I want to convert an array of date-time strings (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) to GPS seconds (seconds after 2000-01-01 12:00:00) in the python environment.

In order to get the GPS seconds for a single date in Linux BASH, I simply input `date2sec datetimestring` and it returns a number.

I could do this within a for-loop within python. But, how would I incorporate this within the python script, as it is an external script?

Or, is there another way to convert an array of date-time strings (or single date-time strings  incorporated into a for-loop) to GPS time without using date2sec?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**: uses Astropy library:

```
from astropy.time import Time

t = Time('2019-12-03 23:55:32', format='iso', scale='utc')
print(t.gps)
```

Here you are setting the date in UTC and `t.gps` converts the datetime to GPS seconds.

**Further research showed that directly using datetime objects doesn't take leap seconds into account.**

other helpful links here:
[How to get current date and time from GPS unsegment time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415475/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-from-gps-unsegment-time-in-python)

Comment: I'm not sure it is the correct answer. The question was about GPS time, and `total_seconds()` docs say nothing. But `timestamp` doc gives us hints (using `total_seconds()`: it uses the POSIX convention and not the GPS convention. I never saw `date2sec` command, so I'm not sure which time are really meant.

Comment: I did further research based on your feedback and found out using Astropy library might be the least complicated approach to the problem. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I used for an entire array of date-times in a for-loop:

```
import numpy as _np
J2000 = _np.datetime64('2000-01-01 12:00:00')                    # Time origin
dateTime = [...]                                                 # an array of date-times in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format
GPSarray_secs = []                                               # Create new empty array
for i in range(0,len(dateTime)) :                                # For-loop conversion
     GPSseconds = (_np.datetime64(dateTime) - J2000).astype(int) # Calculate GPS seconds
     GPSarray_secs = _np.append(GPSarray_secs , GPSseconds)      # Append array
```

The simple conversion for one date-time entry is:

```
import numpy as _np
J2000 = _np.datetime64('2000-01-01 12:00:00')                    # Time origin
GPSseconds = (_np.datetime64(dateTime) - J2000).astype(int)      # Conversion where dateTime is in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format
```

Importing `datetime` should not be required.

Comment: Also your answer is not correct: you may miss some seconds. It uses unix time, so leap seconds will be ignored in the count of seconds. GPS time includes the leap second in the total seconds.