# Python Convert GPS Time 19 digit to UTC

Tags: python-3.x, gps, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

I am reading GPS time off a device which output in a typically long number **1279305882528145920**. Usually it would be 10 digits but I am unsure why this is much longer. I assume it has additional 9 digits for nanosecond accuracy.

I am able to verify the 19 digit gps time is correct with this link [https://www.andrews.edu/~tzs/timeconv/timedisplay.php](https://www.andrews.edu/%7Etzs/timeconv/timedisplay.php) but I am unsure how the gps->unix conversion occurs. I have also read that there could be leap seconds but I am unsure if the device does this. The device I am using is a [VectorNav VN-200](https://www.vectornav.com/products/vn-200).

below is my attempt:

```py
def get_times(gps_time):
    epoch = gps_time/1000000000
    date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", time.localtime(epoch))
    time = time.strftime("%H/%M/%S.%f", time.localtime(epoch))
    
    return epoch, date, time
```

then called with `get_times(1279305882528145920)` which will result in the following error:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '12:05:24.%f')
```

Edit:
If I change `%H/%M/%S.%f` to `%H/%M/%S` my code works but I want to log the milliseconds. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Does it have to be super accurate when converted? Take a look at python's datetime module. Maybe datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp? It returns a datetime object down to millisecond accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will post the answer. It involves with using GPS time at 1980 June 6 and adding the number of seconds onto that. There is also a time drift that occurs that we subtract from the value. In 2020 that drift is 18 and can increase potentially by 2023 to 19. I am unsure how to calculate this so I've hard coded it for now. Hopefully someone can chime in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 19 digit time is GPS time in nanoseconds. GPS Time uses June 6, 1980. This is similar to how Epoch uses January 1, 1970.

Anyways the calculation is done by using 1980 as a starting reference point then adding the number of seconds since then. There is a time drift error which needs to be accounted for. In 2020 that drift is 18.

```py
time_gps = time_gps/1000000000  # Converts ns -> s
gps_start = pd.datetime(year=1980, month=1, day=6)
time_since= pd.to_timedelta(time_gps, unit='s')
error = pd.to_timedelta(19, unit='s')
time_utc = gps_start + time_since - error
print(f'time_utc: {time_gps}')
```

Comment: There's some other detailed approaches for the conversion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415475/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-from-gps-unsegment-time-in-python

Comment: This is great! Thank you for directing me to this. The leap seconds table and explanation is very detailed.